# How do I power on my .vmx file using command line? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, boot, vmware-workstation

I have a desktop shortcut with the following Target:

"C:\VMWareWorkstation.exe" start "C:/dsl.vmx"

This opens VMware Workstation with the file ready to be used, However it does not POWER ON the virtual machine, I know it was a very similar command, however I have forgot and since formatted the machine, I checked VMWARE KB's but got nowhere for Windows commands.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [Vmware](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_learning_cli_vmrun.html) support.

> VMware Workstation includes a separate application, vmrun, for
>   operating teams or virtual machines from the command line.

To launch the vmrun application, from the command prompt, enter:

```
vmrun COMMAND [OPTION]
```

On prompt command:

`vmrun start c:\My Virtual Machines\<virtual_machine_name>.vmx`

Comment: That has worked a treat! Thankyou